# Jira issue description markdown/wiki type

Tags: jira

Is there an official name for the markup used in Jira issues? It's not a flavor of Markdown or wiki syntax I'm familiar with.

Extra points if you have a syntax highlighting plugin for Jira (not Confluence)!

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, never got notified. I suppose the answer is there isn't one, which is unfortunate but perhaps the actual answer.

Also, was looking for a syntax plugin to help write Atlassian markdown (e.g., for Sublime Text).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atlassian has its own [wiki formatting language](https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/WikiRendererHelpAction.jspa?section=all) that is used in JIRA. Syntax highlighting is supported via [`{code}` blocks](https://jira.atlassian.com/secure/WikiRendererHelpAction.jspa?section=advanced):

```
{code:title=Bar.java|borderStyle=solid}
// Some comments here
public String getFoo()
{
    return foo;
}
{code}
```

`{code}` blocks support the following languages:

> The default language is **Java** but you can specify others too, including **ActionScript**, **Ada**, **AppleScript**, **bash**, **C**, **C#**, **C++**, **CSS**, **Erlang**, **Go**, **Groovy**, **Haskell**, **HTML**, **JavaScript**, **JSON**, **Lua**, **Nyan**, **Objc**, **Perl**, **PHP**, **Python**, **R**, **Ruby**, **Scala**, **SQL**, **Swift**, **VisualBasic**, **XML** and **YAML**.